# change child on hover pseudo

Tags: css, pseudo-class, mousehover

I'm trying to achieve to change .more on hover .gfield_description:after
But is this uberhaupt possible this way?

```
<div class="gfield_description">
<div class="more"/>
</div>

.gfield_description:after {
content: "?";
}
.more {opacity:0;}
.gfield_description:hover:after .more {
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to alter .more using :after? also are you using xhtml?

Comment: Using on hover on pseudo elements and not on their parent is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: @BramVanroy that is what I was afraid for. Just needed a confirmation to be sure I'm not losing my mind. thx

Comment: It *is* perfectly possible and valid to use :hover on pseudo elements. You selector needs updating, though: .gfield_description:after:hover .more [ opacity: 1 };. But since the event bubble to the parent, this will also work: .gfield_description:hover .more [ opacity: 1; }

Comment: @connexo And, as you say yourself, restricting the hover event to a pseudo element is not possible. As I said.

Comment: @BramVanroy To be exact, I stated the opposite.

Comment: @connexo You said the hover event wil bubble to the parent element. So - as a consequence - you cannot use `hover` on the pseudo element exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.more {
    opacity: 0;
}
.gfield_description:hover > .more {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This will work due to the event bubbling of :hover on your pseudo element.

Comment: @connexo yes i see, but I can not allow to let to work on hover on the whole .gfield_description element.